# Python write csv if condition is met

Tags: python, csv

I have a file named `y_and_n.csv`, and it looks like this:

```
Y,13,foo
N,19,bar
Y,37,boo
Y,71,fiz
N,29,buz
```

What's the best way to write a code in Python that saves a new file, `y_only.csv`, which would look like the text below?

```
Y,13,foo
Y,37,boo
Y,71,fiz
```

Comment: What has thou tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write the following.

```
yn = open("y_and_n.csv",'r')
y = open("y_only.csv",'w',newline='')

for i in yn:
    if i[0] == 'Y':
        y.write(i)

yn.close()
y.close()
```

Comment: If you want to split each line into a list an check with that, then `line.split(',')` will do the trick for you.

Answer (score -1):

Plain Python has a very good module for reading/writing csv files, named [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

The basic structure of a reader is:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Therefore,  you shold substitute print(row) for one if structure, selecting only the rows you want to print. Rows are lists, so you should use [] to access columns, as in row[0] for first column.

You should only remember that the row is read as a list of strings.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat similar to GarethPW's answer, but using `csv` and a generator expression:

```
import csv
with open("y_and_n.csv") as open_file:
    rows = list(csv.reader(open_file))

with open("y_only.csv", "w") as open_file:
    writer = csv.writer(open_file)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row[0] == "Y")
```